# Strictly decreasing function $f(n)>f(n+1)$ is not definable in $\mathbb{N}$ (Set Theoretic (Neumann's) construction of $\mathbb{N}$).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm studying some Set Theory now and I oppose to a problem which I guess it is related to well ordering of Natural numbers.
The problem is:

Prove that there is no function $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ which for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $f(n+1) < f(n)$.

$\\$

Maybe we answer it as below:

If there is any, we should have $f(0)>f(1)>f(2)>f(3)>\dots$ and it's not the case because the set of Natural numbers is not "left-unbounded".

but the MAIN problem is I must use the set theoretic construction of Natural numbers (Neumann's construction which is based on $\varnothing$ set. ($0=\varnothing, 1=\{\varnothing\}, 2=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\},\dots$)).

How can I describe well-ordering in $\mathbb{N}$ or what do I should to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See Elements of set theory by Herbert B. Enderton http://books.google.com.br/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=%22von+neumann+construction%22+%22set+theory%22&source=bl&ots=m9xWMb1CgU&sig=bMXUA0Rs49CDCnNO7-wDw51QRw0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wwGkUKyYL42z0QGcu4DwDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22von%20neumann%20construction%22%20%22set%20theory%22&f=true

Comment: thank you Elias, It's useful to know more for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you know that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered by $<$. This means that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a least element. Now, $\{ f(n)\, :\, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is certainly a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and so it has a least element. Is this possible if $f$ is strictly decreasing?

If you need to *show* that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, you'll first need to tell me what set-theoretic construction you're using! (I've removed the answer I previously left about von Neumann's construction etc.)

---

**Added:** You can prove by induction that $\mathbb{N}$, as constructed in your post, has no infinite descending $\in$-chains. First note that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n$ is a natural number, so it suffices to show that no natural number $n$ has an infinite descending $\in$-chain.

The base case is just $\varnothing$: the length of the longest $\in$-chain is $0$ since it has no elements at all!

Now suppose that all $\in$-chains in the set $n$ have length $\le n$. (That is, if $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k \in n$ and $a_1 \in a_2 \in \cdots \in a_k$ then $k \le n$.) Prove from this that all $\in$-chains in the set $n+1 = n \cup \{ n \}$ have length $\le n+1$.

Comment: I don't believe you need Foundation to show that $\in$ defines a well ordering on $\mathbb{N}$.  (At least if you identify $\mathbb{N}$ with the least inductive set you can show that no element of $\mathbb{N}$ contains itself; Jech's _Set Theory (3rd ed)_ has a series of exercises in the Chapter 1 which establishes this.)

Comment: @RR: Maybe I was confused about what you mean by 'set theoretic definition'. What did you mean? I've updated my answer to give something less ZFC.

Comment: @Clive Newstead: Thank you for your help Clive.
I have updated my question to make it more clear.
I use Neumann's construction as described in updated question.
If we may not use Foundation Axiom, how we answer to this problem?
it seems my approach to this question is not true! (isn't it?)

Comment: @RR: I've added to my answer.

Comment: @RR: Is something wrong? I notice you accepted and then un-accepted the answer.

Comment: @Clive Newstead: I've confused Clive!
1st: We construct $\mathbb{N}$ by means of Neumann's method. but how can you use Natural numbers for counting members of the set $n$?( I mean the indices of $a_i$'s)
2nd: I understand from your offer that I can use your argument as below:
suppose that $n=f(0)$ then all members of $\mathbb{N}$ except $n$ itself is member of $n$.
is it the case?
3rd: How can we find such sequence of numbers which contribute in an $\in$-chain?

$\\$

I so confused now!

Comment: @CliveNewstead: May I ask you tell me how I could prove well ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ using construction which I described?

Comment: @RR: The construction you defined is precisely the recursive definition: $0=\varnothing$ and $n+1=n \cup \{n\}$. Then, for instance, $5 = \{ 0,1,2,3,4 \}$. And it then holds that $m<n$ if and only if $m \in n$. So a $\in$-chain is the same thing as a $<$-chain.

Comment: The bit about counting the $a_i$s is an induction argument. For instance, suppose every chain in $5$ has length $\le 5$ (this must be so: the longest chain is $0 \in 1 \in 2 \in 3 \in 4$). Then the longest chain in $6$ has length $\le 6$, since if $a_1 \in \cdots \in a_k$ with each $a_i \in 6$ then in particular $a_k \in 6$, so $a_{k-1} \in k$ for some $k<6$ (and therefore $a_{k-1} \in 5$), and so $k-1 \le 5$ and $k \le 6$. You just do this with $5$ replaced by $n$ and so on. (Sorry it's hard to do a good job of explaining things in the comments.)

Comment: Oh, my fault, I beg your pardon.